# Tumbler is driving me CRAZY... how can I remove it?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu

Every single time I cut, copy, paste or even rename a folder, tumblerd goes crazy, uses tons of CPU and my HDD starts making a really loud and irritating grinding noise that just doesn't stop.

Even if I move a folder with 1 single file inside it.... tumblerd goes absolutely nuts for ages.

I have to constantly open a terminal and `killall tumblerd` every time I do anything, but I'm really sick and tired of it now. It's come to the point where I dread moving or renaming anything on my system because of the constant tumblerd grinding.

The problem is it cant even be removed without removing vital components along with it.

Searching google I can see lots of posts, every year, multiple times a year, for the past 8 years... and this is still and absolute nightmare of a problem.

Is there any way to stop this god-awful thing?

I'm on Xubuntu 20.04

Comment: try `systemctl stop tumblerd` and `systemctl disable tumblerd`

Comment: A search of the Tumbler bug tracker reports seems to show that no long-suffering users have shown the XFCE developers a clear working example of the problem that they can duplicate in order to troubleshoot. Perhaps you can make a difference for the entire community.

Comment: @Jean-Marie unfortunately no luck: Failed to disable unit: Unit file tumblerd.service does not exist. User: Any user of any version of Xubuntu for at least the past 18+ months could replicate this problem simply by cutting/copying + pasting or renaming any folder on their device.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting this? I don't know how to fix it but;  Maybe it would be at least somewhat helpful to explain why downvotes?  Or is it me that are a bit .. after?   Sorry if that's the case. I just try to,  first help then, maybe critic/downvote. :/   Have  a good day everyone !  Again;sorry if this was wrong.

Comment: Guys, I had really bad time with tumbler. I checked it with strace and every time after moving directories it is reading old thumbnail files for no reason. Like 20 000 of them. I switched to Nemo and my SSD is quiet so far.

Comment: @Rolandas Dundulis But Nemo is a file manager, does it use something other than tumbler to create thumbnails? How does installing Nemo stop the problem with tumbler?

Comment: @Johnny5ive, yes, tumbler is only a thunar thing. Now i removed tumbler but kept thunar. Other file managers do thumbnailing internally or use something else. Anyway I would still ideally would love to use thunar and have thumbnails sane way. I still didn't find alternatives, so I am thinking to fork tumbler and make less aggressive version of it, but have to find time for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many months of putting up with this service thrashing my HDD every time I move or rename anything I've been able to remove it. Simply:

`sudo apt remove tumbler` (note this also prompts that `ubuntu-desktop` will be removed, however after noticing [this post](https://miteshjlinuxtips.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/stopping-tumblerd-in-xfce/#comment-208) I decided to give it a try and after a reboot I can confirm Xubuntu 20.04.2 is running as normal and files and folders can be moved or renamed without the horrendous HDD thrashing)

Side note: I guess people with SSD's may not notice this problem but the damage that it will be doing to their drives would likely be significant.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the thumbnailer but this will disable thumbnail previews in Thunar. Anyhow, the solution is to change every instance of `Disabled=false` to `Disabled=true` in your `/etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc`. You can run the following command to do this automatically.

```
sudo sed -i 's/false/true/g'
```

Log out and log back in or kill Tumblerd and/or Tumbler to apply the changes.

---

You can also try fine tuning this file by enabling some (`Disabled=false`) and disabling others (`Disabled=true`) if you want to keep some of the thumbnail capabilities.

Just edit the file with your favorite text editor using `sudo` like in the following example which uses `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/tumbler/tumbler.rc
```

To save your changes in `nano`, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Source: [How to Fix Excessive CPU Usage by Process Tumblerd on XFCE Desktop — askmeaboutlinux.com](https://askmeaboutlinux.com/2016/07/06/how-to-fix-excessive-cpu-usage-by-process-tumblerd-on-xfce-desktop-in-linux/)

---

Additionally, the problem you describe with the disk paging or "thrashing" is often an indication that your swap space is too small or that swappiness is set too low on a system with limited resources. It is often recommended by people to disable swap to increase performance but on a system with limited resources, swap actually increases performance.

If you haven't made any changes to swappiness, this probably isn't the issue. If you have made changes to swappiness, this may be something to look into if the changes above (disabling Tumblerd) don't seem to help.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that hasn't stopped it. I changed all to true but even after a reboot, tumblerd is still thrashing (an apt word for it) my HDD. I think I'll try removing access to my home folder using firejail, hopefully that should stop it.